# How to customise appearance of DAGs using dagitty

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs

I am using dagitty online browser to draw DAGs for a project: http://www.dagitty.net/dags.html#

I cannot figure out how to customise the appearance of my DAGs to make them look nice, for inclusion in a paper. Code and images are provided at the end of the post.

I would like to be able to do any of the below:
A) Use superscripts instead of underscores
B) Change the size of the font
C) In the 'classic' style, the variable names cover the arrows in the arrow is going directly up, so you cannot see the direction of causality
D) Just have variable names representing each node, instead of boxes

In the [paper](https://academic.oup.com/ije/article/45/6/1887/2907796) explaining how to use the R package of this tool, there are many DAGs which have the above mentioned properties, but the focus of the paper is to explain how to use DAGs to properly assess causality etc, nothing about the appearance of the DAGs. I would be very grateful for some help on this, or for suggestions of other tools/packages that allow you to draw DAGs. I also fear this may be better placed on the maths/statistics stack, which will likely have more users of the dagitty tool. Mods please move there if appropiate. I posted here as it's purely a coding issue.

The following code can be input in the 'model code' section of the dagitty website to reproduce the two DAG images I have provided. By choosing 'classic' or 'SEM-like' under the Diagram style, you can get the two appearances.

```
dag {
T_0 [adjusted,pos="-1.575,0.494"]
X_0 [adjusted,pos="-1.574,0.280"]
Y [outcome,pos="-1.288,0.250"]
T_0 -> X_0
T_0 -> Y
X_0 -> Y
}
```

DAG1
[image: DAG1: SEM-like]

DAG2
[image: DAG2: Classic]

**EDIT:**

Using dagitty package in R and ggdag gets the nicer aesthetics on the DAG image. Thank you for the response Sebastian. However it does not seem to respect positioning co-ordinates for lines to make them curved. This is an issue in creating the DAG I want to create in my actual work. To continue with the example above, the following code gets a curved line between T_0 and Y:

```
dag {
T_0 [adjusted,pos="-1.575,0.494"]
X_0 [adjusted,pos="-1.574,0.280"]
Y [outcome,pos="-1.288,0.250"]
T_0 -> X_0
T_0 -> Y [pos="-1.400,0.500"]
X_0 -> Y
}
```

Producing this image:

[image: DAG curved]

But this does not happen when using dagitty and ggdag in R. The exact same code produces a DAG with straight lines. Is it possible to produce curved lines through specific co-ordinates in R with dagitty and ggdag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the R package `ggdag`, see [here](https://ggdag.netlify.app/index.html), also, checkout the manual [here](http://www.dagitty.net/manual-3.x.pdf)

Comment: Thank you Sebastian. ggdag does this automatically which is great. However, it does not respect edge co-ordinates which create curved edges through specific points (necessary in larger DAGs to ensure edges do not go directly through nodes). Do you know if it is possible to specify edge positions, like in the dagitty tool online? See edit to question.